# How to check whether a review link is accessible?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, review

I'm doing a iPhone app and there are review requests from within the app. I want to show the requests only when the review link is accessible. (You cannot expect users to give reviews when there's no network at all.) How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Reachability to check network status:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

However, you might want to read my recent blog post about getting 5 star reviews and re-think your strategy:

http://thedistance.co.uk/journal/2012-01/how-to-get-more-5-star-app-reviews

[Spoiler: Don't use modal alerts]

Comment: It worked, thanks. And also thanks for the strategy guide. However I still decide to use modal alerts, only once, to users who completed several levels. Later the 'Review Us' would reside in the options menu. (This follows the strategy:))

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for your purpose I think [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) is really helpful, it also does the network checking for you and so on.